# Import Excel file that has carriage return / line feeds within cells into SQL Server 2008 R2 and preserve the carriage return / line feeds?

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to import an Excel file that has carriage return / line feeds within cells into SQL Server 2008 R2 and preserve the carriage return / line feeds? The Excel file has about 81,000 rows.

I tried using the import wizard with no success. I ended up creating the table and then cut and pasting the rows in, but the order skews when it gets to the cells that have the carriage return / line feeds. Anyone know of a fix for this?

I'm importing into a SQL Server 2008 R2 database from Excel 2007. The Excel file has cells that have carriage return / line feed. The error I receive is truncation and special character issues -- same issue even when I change to `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`. So I gave up and created the the table without row data, then cut and pasted the rows from Excel directly into SQL Server 2008 R2. The issue during cut and paste is with the cells that have the carriage return / line feed.

Comment: can you elaborate what problem you are facing when exporting to database ?? what kind of error it's showing

Comment: I'm importing into sql server 2008 r2 database from excel 2007.  The excel file has cells that have carriage return / line feed.  The error I receive is truncation and special character issues -- same issue even when I change to varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).  So I gave up and created the the table without row data, then cut and pasted the rows from excel directly into sql server.  The issue during cut and paste is with the cells that have the carriage return / line feed.

Comment: Please update the question with these details, comments are harder to read (especially long ones)

Comment: can you please post the top 2 rows of sample data of your excel sheet so that i can try..mine is also 2008r2 edition

Comment: Spreadsheet has medical information ... HIPPA rules won't allow :(  The issue is easily created just go into excel and enter text into a cell use alt+enter to line feed and continue typing text.  This method produces a cell with line feeds.  Do this with a small paragraph, then try to import or cut and past it into sql server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this is a bit simplistic, but worth a try.

Create a new column using the formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),"|")
```

to replace the line feeds with another character.

So in practice this would have to go in a new sheet and refer back to the original sheet

```
=SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!A2,CHAR(10),"|")
```

with all the other columns copied across as well, then you would import from this new sheet.

Unfortunately I can't test the import until next week when I'm back at work, but [this](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/sql-server-insert-carriage-return-line-feed-to-string) suggests how you might replace the filter character (or whatever single character or sequence of characters you choose to use) with a carriage return in SQL.